# Issue creating login page with spring hibernate and mysql using spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple login web application using spring mvn with hibernate and spring security, but getting the following error. Application works fine when I remove spring security. I don't know how to fix the issue.

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a228ecb: defining beans [org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,userDetailsService,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint,securityFilter,homeController,userDAOImpl,customUserDetailsService,userServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3746)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1350)
```

My java classes are

```
package com.analyst.future.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.analyst.future.domain.User;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String userEmail) {
        List<User> users = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from User where email=?")
                .setParameter(0, userEmail).list();

        return users.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(user);

    }

    @Override
    public User deleteUser(String email) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.analyst.future.service;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.analyst.future.dao.UserDAO;
import com.analyst.future.domain.User;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String userEmail) {
        return userDAO.getUser(userEmail);

    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userDAO.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User deleteUser(String email) {
        return userDAO.deleteUser(email);
    }

}
```

and servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/future" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="accessme11" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.analyst.future.domain.User</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.analyst.future.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.analyst.future.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.analyst.future" />



</beans:beans>
```

Can anyone kindly tell me what is the issue in my code. When i start the tomcat server, i get the above error on console.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <!-- <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value> <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> -->

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You need to use @Autowired instead of @Resource on top of `sessionFactory` variable declaration in `UserDAOImpl`

Comment: can you share your web.xml as well? and does it work without spring security when you mention it in heading?

Comment: @sodik i have added web.xml file. Arkantos i used Autowired but it also not working.

Comment: does it works without spring security? does your spring security use your beans, e.g. in UserDetailService? because spring security context can't get to your beans defined in your servlet-context.xml

Comment: Yes, it is working with out spring security.

Comment: @sodik can you kindly tell me how to fix it.

Comment: does it mean that you are using `userDAOImpl` (or at least you do component scan) in spring-security.xml , right? you are mixin XML and anotation, remove one of them. (and maybe also post your spring-security.xml - if you say it works without it)

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` wires by type and `@Resource` wires by name.

So you can change it to `Autowired` to inject `SessionFactory` in your   `UserDAOImpl` class like below

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

(Or) You can mention the resource name in the annotation like this

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Here `sessionFactory` is the exact name/id given to Hibernate SessionFactory bean defined in your `servlet-context.xml`

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

Comment: I changed it to @Resource(name="sessionFactory") and now getting "no bean named 'sessionFactory' found

Comment: Hmm.. it should pick the bean definition matching the id as well but you can try specifying both `name` and `id` in your `servlet-context.xml` for that bean

Comment: changed the defination to  <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory" but still not working

Comment: Looks like you're already referring to dependencies in `servlet-context.xml` with `property` tags and you're using annotations in your classes, you should do only one of them not both :) Also if you plan to drop annotations, you should create setters for those properties and it will work with your current bean definitions. If not, you can remove the property tags and use autowiring to inject your dependencies

Comment: I removed the property  <!--  <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> --> but still not working. Is there any chance the the bean does not created, and "Resource" or "Autowired" is pointing to a bean that does not exists. As i am getting message like "No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency"